# AngularJS - how to sync result of calculated input field to a scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to sync the result of a calculated form field into a scope variable. For example:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="val1" class="control-label">Val 1</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="val1" type="number" ng-model="data.val1" id="val1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="val2" class="control-label">Val 2</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="val2" type="number" ng-model="data.val2" id="val2">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="score" class="control-label">Score</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="score" value="{{data.val1+data.val2}}" type="text" id="score">
</div>
<br/>data: {{data}}
```

How can I sync the result (i.e. the score field) into the scope variable $scope.data.score? I have tried `ng-model="data.score"` but that breaks the calculation.

You can see the example in action here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fc9XcyyYGtAk0aGVV35t?p=preview

How do I get the last line to read `data: {"val1":1,"val2":2,"score":3}`?

Note that I'm looking for a solution that involves **minimal to no code support at the controller level**. For example, I know you can set up a watch in the controller for both val1 and val2 and then update the score in the watcher. This is what I wanted to avoid, if it's possible in angular at all. If it's not (theoretically) possible, I'd really appreciate an explanation of why it's not.

A quick background might help. Basically we have a simple form builder app that defines a form and all its fields in an xml file. Here's a sample of what the xml would look like:

```
<form name="test">
    <field name="val1" control="textbox" datatype="number">
        <label>Val 1</label>
    </field>
    <field name="val2" control="textbox" datatype="number">
        <label>Val 2</label>
    </field>
    <field name="score" control="textbox" datatype="number">
        <label>Score</label>
        <calculate>[val1]+[val2]</calculate>
    </field>    
</form>
```

When a form is requested, the system will need to pick up the xml, loop through all the fields and generate an angular style html to be served to the browser and processed by angular. Ideally, I want to keep all the form specific logic (validation, show/hide, calculation etc) confined to the html, and keep the controller (js) logic generic for all forms.

The only solution I can come up with is to dynamically load watcher functions, through something like this: `eval("$scope.$watch('[data.val1,data.val2]')...")`, but as I said, I really want to avoid this, because it's just tedious, and feels extremely dodgy :)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vVT2GTZZYfEWmtEfTtQc?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The first dirty way.**

In your case you can move all logic from controller into html with using combination of `ng-init` and `ng-change` directives.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="val1" class="control-label">Val 1</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="val1" type="number" ng-model="data.val1" ng-change="data.score = data.val1 + data.val2" id="val1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="val2" class="control-label">Val 2</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="val2" type="number" ng-model="data.val2" ng-change="data.score = data.val1 + data.val2" id="val2">
</div>
<div class="form-group" ng-init="data.score = data.val1 + data.val2">
  <label for="score" class="control-label">Score</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="score" ng-model="data.score" type="text" id="score">
</div>
<br/>data: {{data}}
```

I don't think that it's the clearest solution, but you can leave your controller without any changes with it.

[Demo on plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/eyt0rZKo4vz0y71JUVGq?p=preview)

**The second dirty way.**

There is one more way, but now you don't need `ng-init` and `ng-change` directives. You can add just one dirty expression in html:

```
<div id="main-container" class="container" style="width:100%" ng-controller="MainController">
{{data.score = data.val1 + data.val2;""}} <!-- key point -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="val1" class="control-label">Val 1</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="val1" type="number" ng-model="data.val1" id="val1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="val2" class="control-label">Val 2</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="val2" type="number" ng-model="data.val2" id="val2">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="score" class="control-label">Score</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="score" ng-model="data.score" type="text" id="score">
</div>
<br/>data: {{data}}
```

**;""** in expression stops evaluating of angular expression to text in html.

[Demo on plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/I3ojzc?p=preview)

Comment: It's still not ideal, but it does at least allow me to keep all logic in the html. I'll flag this as answer until someone comes up with a better one.

Comment: I add another dirty solution. %) I updated my answer.

Comment: That is pure genius mate! It keeps all logic in html, and I don't have to worry about ng-changing the correct field(s). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

See if this works, in your HTML change,

```
 <input class="form-control" name="score"  ng-model = "data.score" type="text" id="score">
```

and, in your controller do,

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', [])

    .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = { val1: 1, val2: 2, score: 3};

        $scope.$watch('[data.val1,data.val2]', function (newValue, oldValue) {
              $scope.data.score = newValue[0] + newValue[1];
        }, true);
})
```

Demo plunk,  http://plnkr.co/edit/gS0UenjydgId4H5HwSjL?p=preview

Comment: That's not really practical for me. Although it works well in this particular case, what I'm ultimately trying to do is to be able to take an xforms style xml definition for a form and render it as a template for angular to process. For example, I'll need to parse the following field definition: `<field label="Score" calculate="[var1+[var2]"/>` and transform it into angular template. It's probably possible to use regex to find all [var] and manually write inline js to $watch them, but it's going to be really messy. I was hoping for a more elegant solution, if there is one :)

Comment: Essentially I'm looking for a way to watch for the change in value of a form field, whether the change is from a direct user input or system initiated, and update a scope variable accordingly.

Comment: I have edited the plunk, so please have a look at it and see if it works for you, and if it is what you want.   http://plnkr.co/edit/58Ss85SEDhfF2l9TNWzA?p=preview

Comment: It still involves having to: 1) manually inject js code into the controller scope and 2) parse the "calculate" formula and work out all the contributing variables. This updated solution is actually less desirable since when I'm generating the html for the "score" field, I would have to somehow update the html for the val1 and val2 fields as well, which is tricky to fit into the html generation routine, which essentially go through the list of field definitions (from xml file) top-down and generate html for each, one at a time. I'm sorry if I haven't explained the big picture clearer.

Comment: I've updated by question, adding a bit more background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how you can do it, then i have one solution for you make a ng-change event for both of your text box and sum both the number there and use ng-model in the third text box then, you can see it will work as per your need.

For the first time load you need to calculate it out side only.